# Why Typescript doesn't complain about this?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm so confused, when I assign a superset type to their subset type in the `useState` hook, why would Typescript not complain about mismatched type? And if it's intended, how should I type the `useState` hook to make it complain properly?
`

```js
interface Animal {
    name: string;
    food: string;
    legs: number;
}

interface Dog {
    name: string;
    food: string;
}

const animal: Animal = {
    name: 'animal',
    food: 'animal food',
    legs: 4,
};

function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState<Dog>(animal);
    ...
}
```

Comment: You can use the pattern of "Branded Types" to differentiate between `Dog` and `Animal`: https://typescript.tv/best-practices/improve-your-type-safety-with-branded-types/ - Using a branded type will enforce you to use an assertion functions to validate your types before using them.

Answer (score 3):

A static type checker can use either the name (nominal typing) or the structure (structural typing) of types when comparing them against other types (like when checking if one is a `subtype` of another).

TypeScript uses a structure typing system.

See [Type Compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#starting-out).

> Type compatibility in TypeScript is based on structural subtyping. Structural typing is a way of relating types based solely on their members. This is in contrast with nominal typing.

> The basic rule for TypeScript’s structural type system is that `x` is compatible with `y` if `y` has at least the same members as `x`

V.S. [Nominal typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system)

> Nominal typing means that two variables are type-compatible if and only if their declarations name the same type. For example, in C, two struct types with different names in the same translation unit are never considered compatible, even if they have identical field declarations.

Languages like C++, Java, and Swift have primarily nominal type systems.

```java
// Pseudo code: nominal system
class Foo { method(input: string) { /* ... */ } }
class Bar { method(input: string) { /* ... */ } }

let foo: Foo = new Bar(); // Error!
```

Languages like Go, TypeScript and Elm have primarily structural type systems

```
// Pseudo code: structural system
class Foo { method(input: string) { /* ... */ } }
class Bar { method(input: string) { /* ... */ } }

let foo: Foo = new Bar(); // Works!
```

---

One way to declare nominal typing in TypeScript:

```
interface Animal {
    name: string;
    food: string;
    legs: number;
}

interface Dog {
    name: string;
    food: string;
}

type Brand<T, K> = T & { __brand: K }

type AnimalNominal = Brand<Animal, 'animal'>;
type DogNominal = Brand<Dog, 'dog'>

const animal: AnimalNominal = {
    name: 'animal',
    food: 'animal food',
    legs: 4,
    __brand: 'animal'
};

const dog: DogNominal = {
    name: 'hot dog',
    food: 'dog food',
    __brand: 'dog'
}

const s1: AnimalNominal = animal // ok
const s2: AnimalNominal = dog; // error

const s3: DogNominal = animal; // error
const s4: DogNominal = dog; // ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwChkTkQ5MIAuZAZzClAHMBuY0mAe04BMb7GIVuxI4ITWjRABXTACNobAL6FCoSLEQoAIpyYERZCtToNmbUsi69+ZoctVgAngAcUAIShwQPADwAVABpkAGkAPmQAXmR-ZAAyAmQAfSS5Lx8aEOQVQmc3NAxsHAA5TkxQXCjkT28-dCxcYIBybwacJrC2PJ09UvLyPGian19dJmaePQ7VBE4QemRWopp6or6KwYNLckoaFsLcJsDDaz5kfbarbh4jwzEJGgAWY8sUtNq9pcPCJTZCWfmYGQkyYNDG6wGVSI22MewAFpwgSDbpZTnsQVdeCjSG90mcmsifjM5gtaABGFYHEplDZVL54AD0DOQnAA1v8SUDaAAmSltCGVaIgljIJnIaBQThQYmAugAZjBvRpkOi9JFYolUo5stoj0VTAFm2FouZbKAA)

Nominal typing proposal: https://github.com/Microsoft/Typescript/issues/202

The [`Brand<T, U>`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utility-types#brandt-u) type of `utility-types` package.

> Define nominal type of U based on type of T

Answer (score 0):

the assignment to be valid due to type compatibility rules.

TypeScript allows assigning a superset type to a subset type because the superset type contains all the properties and values required by the subset type.

If you want TypeScript to properly complain about the mismatched type, you can explicitly type the `useState()` hook with the desired type. In this case, you would want to specify Animal as the type for the `useState()` hook, as it matches the animal object you are initializing it with.

```
   const [data, setData] = useState<Animal>(animal);
```

Remember that TypeScript type checks are performed statically at compile time,